# How can i make Material UI table scroll horizontally and vertically with fixed header

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

**This is material UI code for the sticky header and vertical scroll I want this with horizontal scroll also. I tried to use overflowX:"auto and scroll on paper but it didn't work" I also tried to use other tables to complete this work but got confused. OverflowX on paper isn't working. **

**For more information or reference please check** https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

```
const columns = [
  { id: 'name', label: 'Name', minWidth: 170 },
  { id: 'code', label: 'ISO\u00a0Code', minWidth: 100 },
  {
    id: 'population',
    label: 'Population',
    minWidth: 170,
    align: 'right',
    format: (value) => value.toLocaleString('en-US'),
  },
  {
    id: 'size',
    label: 'Size\u00a0(km\u00b2)',
    minWidth: 170,
    align: 'right',
    format: (value) => value.toLocaleString('en-US'),
  },
  {
    id: 'density',
    label: 'Density',
    minWidth: 170,
    align: 'right',
    format: (value) => value.toFixed(2),
  },
];

function createData(name, code, population, size) {
  const density = population / size;
  return { name, code, population, size, density };
}

const rows = [
  createData('India', 'IN', 1324171354, 3287263),
  createData('China', 'CN', 1403500365, 9596961),
  createData('Italy', 'IT', 60483973, 301340),
  createData('United States', 'US', 327167434, 9833520),
  createData('Canada', 'CA', 37602103, 9984670),
  createData('Australia', 'AU', 25475400, 7692024),
  createData('Germany', 'DE', 83019200, 357578),
  createData('Ireland', 'IE', 4857000, 70273),
  createData('Mexico', 'MX', 126577691, 1972550),
  createData('Japan', 'JP', 126317000, 377973),
  createData('France', 'FR', 67022000, 640679),
  createData('United Kingdom', 'GB', 67545757, 242495),
  createData('Russia', 'RU', 146793744, 17098246),
  createData('Nigeria', 'NG', 200962417, 923768),
  createData('Brazil', 'BR', 210147125, 8515767),
];

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  container: {
    maxHeight: 440,
  },
});

export default function StickyHeadTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(10);

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
        <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row) => {
              return (
                <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.code}>
                  {columns.map((column) => {
                    const value = row[column.id];
                    return (
                      <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                        {column.format && typeof value === 'number' ? column.format(value) : value}
                      </TableCell>
                    );
                  })}
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
        component="div"
        count={rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching I found that putting maxWidth on the container will allow you to have a vertically and horizontally scrollable table.